# Getting Could not sign-in to google, make sure to call onStart/onStop methods to initialize GoogleApiClient properly

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-signin

Suddenly I am getting the above error while trying to sign in with google in my app. And google sign in failed in my app.

I am using GoogleApiClient to login to my app. Also, I don't set the Goolge play Signing in the app console.

Is this mandatory to set in the Google Play console? I have updated to maxSDk version 34. Any inputs on this.

```
Could not sign-in to google, make sure to call onStart/onStop methods to initialize GoogleApiClient properly.
```